# Chrome SameSite=None; Secure Cookie Settings - Cookies that you access in both a first and third-party context

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, samesite

After the latest Chrome updated  - the third party cookie setting is not working for me. To make it work I have to set **SameSite=None;Secure**. But this require HTTPS connection to work  . How do we make it work for HTTP ?

Answer (score 1):

With the new behaviour in Chrome as defined by [Incrementally Better Cookies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-00#section-3.2) you will only be able to have cookies in a third-party context over HTTPS. I would strongly suggest looking at migrating to HTTPS over trying to make cross-site cookies work over plain HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But still is there any option to set cookie over http using SameSite=None ? My scenario is - calling B.com from A.com by passing some value , the B.Com will set that a cookie in B.com. Before I had to set third party access by setting cores . With new updates in Chrome, it is not working. Both A.com and  B.com are same site and code in my case.

Comment: No. Chrome will only allow cross-site cookies over HTTPS.